# cil get varinfo from vid

Tags: frama-c

I have some question when using a Frama-c program in old version. It used the function `varinfo_from_vid ()` to get `varinfo`. 
In the change log I saw that it has been removed and can use maps or hash tables indexed by varinfo to get it.
 I am not quite understand since I am new to cil and frama-c. Does it mean that I need to keep a (`vid`,`varinfo`) hashtable by myself and pass it to every function that has used `variunfo_from_vid()`? Or there are other ways to do that. If some one has example or advice, I would be really appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The plug-in should be transformed to hold `varinfo` directly instead of `int` that represent the `vid` field of a `varinfo`. There is no good reason to store only the `vid` field, and this does not play well with Frama-C's internals, especially projects.

If the plug-in contains tables that are indexed by `int` (`IntHash.t` or `Datatype.Int.Hashtbl.t`), where the keys are in fact `vid`, they should also be replaced by tables that are indexed by `varinfo` (`Cil_datatype.Varinfo.Hashtbl.t`). More information about datatypes in Frama-C can be found in section 4.9.2 of [Frama-C developer manual](http://frama-c.com/download/plugin-development-guide-Neon-20140301.pdf).